# every calculation must be done twice to get an answer

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Would really appreciate if someone can help with this problem:

When I first open a Mathematica note book, say you do 1+2 and press shift-enter.  As expected, I get "3" as the output.

Now suppose you want to 4+5.  But after pressing shift-enter, the program just sits on it, without giving 9 as the answer.

Only way to get the output was to abort the evaluation, and to re-execute it.

This happens for any other calculation (other than the very first one you run in the session).  What this means that every calculation I have to do twice to get the output.

This has never happened to me in last 25 years of use, and I cannot seem to find the problem.  Even uninstalled the program and reinstalled it and still doing the same thing.

By the way, I am running Mathematica version 9(64bit) on Windows 7(64bit)

Thank you so much for any help.

Tim

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72332/mathematica-shift-enter-problem#comment198374_72332

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you behind web proxy on your network? I had similar problem with M9 on W7 if Mathematica tried to connect to Wolfram servers and the proxy was not set correctly.

Go to **Edit/Preferences** and try to test Internet connectivity on the card **Internet Connectivity**. If it will not work, try to set Proxy settings manualy (the automated method "Use proxy settings from my system" doesn't work well).